# How to log an event as Critical using WriteEvent

Tags: c#, .net, windows, event-log, event-viewer

I am trying to set an event level as Critical using the below method:

```
WriteEvent(id, categoryName, EventSeverity.ErrorCritical, entry);
```

But in the event log it only show event level as Error instead of Critical.
Is there any other configuration and parameter I need to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.EventSeverity`? It's used by ShP and maps to its own event log.

The correct way to use `System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType` which maps to Windows event log:

```
Error
Warning
Information
SuccessAudit
FailureAudit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I am using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.EventSeverity as this is on a SharePoint Project.

Comment: @user1551413: I think ShP event log entry type maps to windows event log entry type indirectly what you do observe.

Comment: I see. I have seen SharePoint default events set as Critical in the event viewer but was unable to do using the method.

Comment: I tried using System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType but still cannot set the Event Level. Are you able to give me some guidance?

Comment: @user1551413: I think Windows Event Log support maximum criticality as Error, not Critical.

Comment: @user1551413: Thanks for accepting :) What solution have you chosen finally? Could you please share?